# Trying to call node js REST api using loop sending only last call set of parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

In my application I am using AngularJS and nodeJS for rest api and its working fine. But when I try to call api using for loop its having some problems. Actually only last set of Parameters are passing to the api.

It means if I pass different parameters using loop  3 times then only last set of parameters passing to the api 3 times. First and Second are not send to api. Can anybody have any Idea??

Here is a sample code I use in Angularjs Factory.

```
var firstTimeData = {
                        "firstid": serializedJsonData.firstid,
                        "secondid": serializedJsonData.secondid,
                        "otherid": serializedJsonData.otherid

                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                            firstTimeData.dshdetailid = data[i][j].dshdetailid;
                            if ((data[i][j].defaultTitle).trim() == 'Scorecard Graph') {
                                BlankApi.getData(firstTimeData, 'slide' + j, 'periodname', 'amount');
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?rq=1 for a detailed explanation about  your question

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you have to make asynchronous calls in loop,

Here in this code for loop get continuously executed without waiting for each api call to get finished.

[Refer this post to get idea about how to use asynchronous calls in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662691/how-to-use-asynchronous-calls-in-a-loop-in-angular)

Comment: I tried that but still that sending the same parameter again and again.

Comment: check whether you are getting different parameters in each iteration through loop?